# Memcached on linux not showing in phpinfo

Tags: php, linux, debian, memcached

I have installed memcached `sudo apt-get install memcached`.
I also tried to start and restart it. 
Actually, I can see this service on my services list but when I open phpinfo() there is nothing about it in there.

The problem is that all the step by step guides on the internet are about windows installation. Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Well,what distro do you use? Your apache is running?
As I see in the question, you probably use a distro like debian so:

1- You don´t have your php.ini into the location of phpinfo().

**Source:** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832387/php-extension-memcachememcached-not-showing-in-phpinfo-but-showing-in-php)

2- Problem with php version. (Best way to solve this is reinstall package)

3- In /usr/local/lib/php.ini add this line to the last: `extension=memcache.so`

Hope, this answer help you!

Comment: I am using linuxMint based on Debian.
1. phpinfo is showing the configuration file location correctly (i am using lampp btw)
2. should i reinstall entire lampp once again? ouch
3. i have already added this somewhere below other extensions and restarted lampp but it didnt help

Comment: Ok, tell me if your apache works fine and your php version. I have Mint too so I can help better.

Comment: `php -v` shows me `PHP 7.0.8` some tutorials say i should also try `sudo apt-get install php5-memcache` but it says "cant locate package". Uh thats not easy to me :X ps. looks like my apache works fine

Comment: Oh ok, try to install `sudo apt-get install php-memcache` instead of 
 `sudo apt-get install memcached` (remove memcached first). Probably this give you few packages that php need to run with memcache.

Comment: Okay I just did 1. `sudo apt-get purge memcached`, 2. `sudo apt-get install php-memcache`, 3. `sudo apt-get install php5-memcache` gave me the same error, 4. `sudo apt-get install memcached`.
Hmm after restarting lampp it still not working. Not sure what happens actually xD

Comment: Install php-memcache not php5-memcache if you have the php-7.0 version.